# Time Field on Data Load - "value not of required type: 5:33 PM"

Tags: custom-field, data-loader, time

I am attempting to insert some records on a custom object that requires a value in the `Time Received` field, of type `Time`. Within an existing record (created manually) the value inside the detail page, as well as within a report, appears to be in `HH:MM _M`.

I have tried inserting the following permutations:

- `5:33 PM`
- `5:33PM`
- `5:33:00 PM`
- `17:33`
- `17:33:00`

I've been unable to find clear documentation on the specifics of inserting values to these fields via API. [Their field type doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_field_time_overview.htm&type=5) does not clearly explain how to insert without error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was experiencing this same issue but managed to get the import to work by appending `.000Z` to the end of the `hh:mm:ss` format

As an example:

```
Start Time  End Time
14:00:00.000Z   16:00:00.000Z
14:00:00.000Z   16:00:00.000Z
14:00:00.000Z   16:00:00.000Z
14:00:00.000Z   16:00:00.000Z
14:00:00.000Z   16:00:00.000Z
12:00:00.000Z   15:00:00.000Z
```

Solution based on Salesforce article [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000272063&language=en_US&type=1)

Comment: As luck would have it, I had this issue again nearly two years later and I came back to this. Don't make my mistake. Capitalize the Z.

Answer (score 1):

I have verified at my DE that Time format in csv `14:40:00` inserts the record correctly.

It shows as 2:40 PM on the record.

[image: Time]

Comment: Unfortunately this does not appear to work for me... https://i.imgur.com/KFTZQ5W.png

Comment: Better create a single record for testing purpose in Notepad++ or textpad and then try try to upload. Dont open the csv in Excel before loading. Let me know it that works

Comment: I will give that a shot soon, unfortunately though not opening the file in excel is likely not an option as this file is sourced from the success file of another insert and slightly modified for upload.

Comment: Basically, you can clone the file in see in excel and for data loading purpose better to open the file in textpad or Notepad++. Sometimes, Excel corrupts the format.

Answer (score 1):

I will need to confirm it, but to best of my knowledge in data loader and any sort of API calls, you need to use full API format, i.e. 14:40:00.000 in your case.

I will work with our doc writer to clear this up in the docs.
Thanks!